# bcdboot creates files, but not booting

Tags: boot, windows-10

I have created an image. I have set up partitions W (windows), S(system) and R(Recovery). I successfully use DISM to image my .wim file to W:, it works and the Windows directory and files are all there.

Now I go to W: in the WIN PE environment and run "bcdboot W:\Windows /s S: /f ALL". This works and creates the boot files on S:, I can check that they are there. I restart the computer and it just goes into a boot loop where it will not load Windows. If I image with a Windows 1803 image using the same partition scheme and run the same bcdboot command then it will boot.

The computer is a Dell Latitude 7490.

Does anyone know what I need to check now? I can mount the image in Windows successfully on another computer.

Comment: Is the computer configured to boot via UEFI or in legacy mode?  Is the disk partitioned as GPT or MBR?  What error message do you get when the boot fails?

Comment: The computer is configured to use UEFI and is partitioned as GPT. There is no message when it fails to boot, it just reboots and ends up in a cycle of trying to boot and rebooting. I have noticed that on systems using the new image the UEFI boot in the bios shows as "KXG50ZNB1T02 NVMe TOSHIBA 1024GB, Partition 1", but the old image shows "Windows Boot Manager".

Comment: Hi, It is the version of Windows PE that I created by downloading the deployment toolkit on 1903 and the Win PE add-in that goes with it so it should be the latest. Can you advise how I can check? Can you expand on system partition being the correct type?

Comment: The link in my previous comment contains all the details about checking the partition type.  I doubt that's your problem, but it doesn't hurt to double-check.

Comment: If you bring up a command line while booted to Windows PE you should be able to use the `ver` command to confirm the version.

Comment: Sorry for missing the link. The partition is FAT32 100MB and hidden.

Comment: PE version is 10.0.18361.1

Comment: The diskpart script which creates the partitions is downloaded from Microsoft. The lines which create the system partition are "create patition efi size=100" and then "format quick fs=fat32 label='System'".

Comment: OK, the `create partition efi` does the right thing, so that's not the problem.  18361 appears to be a preview build, but that might be normal for WinPE, I'm not sure, and it seems unlikely to be the cause of the problem anyway.  Maybe the image is corrupt?  Or there's a bug in 1903 affecting imaging?

Comment: I'm trying another fresh build as I think the one I was given originally might not have been the officially released version of 1903. I will see what happens.

Comment: I created a new image from scratch based on a 1903 downloaded from the 365 portal and managed to get a working image. It must have been the build I started with.